# dojo dialog dynamic content 2

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a specific problem. I try to create dynamic html code by javascript function and than put in dojo dialog content. My javascript function is:

```
function doPushButton(doc, id, action, title, imgRef, text, width, style) {
var tabIndex;
if(arguments.length > 8)
        tabIndex = arguments[8];
    var accessKey;
    if(arguments.length > 9)
        accessKey = arguments[9];
    jt_docWrite('<div class="' + style + '" style="cursor: pointer' + (width > 0 ? ';width:' + width + 'px' : '') + '"', doc);
    if(id != null)
        jt_docWrite(' id="' + id + '"', doc);
    if(tabIndex != null)
        jt_docWrite(' tabindex="' + tabIndex + '"', doc);
    if(accessKey != null)
        jt_docWrite(' accesskey="' + accessKey + '"', doc);
    jt_docWrite(' title="' + title + '" onclick="' + action + '">', doc);
    if(imgRef != null)
        jt_docWriteln('<img class="label_icon right" src="' + imgRef + '"/>', doc);
    if(text != null)
        jt_docWriteln('<span class="label">' + text + '</span>', doc);
    jt_docWriteln('</div>', doc);
}
```

where jt_docWrite and jt_docWriteln are js functions:

```
function jt_docWrite() {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        document.write(arguments[0]);
    }

    if (arguments.length == 2) {
        arguments[1].write(arguments[0]);
    }
}
```

And this doPushButton() function Im calling in dojo dialog.create:

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser"], function(ready, parser){
            ready(function(){
                var dialog = dijit.byId("myDlg");
                dojo.create('div', {
                    innerHTML: "Hello"
                  }, dialog.containerNode);
                  var div = dojo.create('div', {}, dialog.containerNode);
                  dojo.create('div', {

                  innerHTML: doPushButton(document, "yes", "doConfirm()", "", "../image/accept.gif", Res_yes_title, 0, "push_button")

                  }, div);
                  dialog.show();
            });
```

When I use my doPushButton() function before in my html page like `< script > doPushButton(document, "yes", "doConfirm()", "", "../image/accept.gif", Res_yes_title, 0, "push_button")  < /script >`, its work fine, but now I want to put it in dojo dialog, it doesnt work and the result od this function is "undefine". Can somebody help me what is wrong?? Thanks a lot.

Miro

Answer (score 0):

Your `doPushButton` method never returns a value. It calls `jt_docWriteln`, which writes the contained html out to the document. The value for the `innerHTML` property must be either a `Node` or a `String` (which could be HTML), and you are passing it `undefined` since `doPushButton` doesn't return anything.